# Whirlpool freezer not getting cold enough

Tags: repair, refrigerator

I have a Whirlpool freezer (model EV171NYMS03) that is not getting cold enough. It is currently below freezing, but just barely. I replaced the fan motor earlier and that is still running.
When I took everything out and looked at it this morning, I noticed a large amount of frost on the vents near the bottom of the freezer on the inside. I melted the ice/frost with some warm water and also removed the back panel and noticed that the evaporator coils were also covered with ice. I let everything thaw out with the help of some more warm water and put everything back together about an hour later.

Now several hours have passed and it is still hovering just below freezing. Is there anything else I should look for?

Comment: You're probably low on freon, in these cases you have the first part of the evaporator that gets covered with frost but due to low amount of freon, it can't manage to cool all the freezer so compressor running 24/7, ice build up near on evaporator and high temperatures inside.

Comment: Another thing you could check if the defrost element: if it's not running it allows the build-up of ice on the evaporator not letting air being cooled.

Comment: I kinda suspect the defrost element.  The new motor did not have a way to connect it to the wiring harness. When I replaced the fan motor I was told that it was not important.  I now know that was bad advice.  So how do I hook that thing back up?

Comment: Call the tech that made the wrong repair and ask him to fix it under warrenty (warrenty on the repair itself, not the fridge one). It's your right, at least here in Italy.

Comment: Did you just change the fan motor because it was not cooling enough? Is the compressor running all the time? If the compressor is shutting down it could be a thermostat problem. It could also be a low Freon problem and the evaporator is icing due to low refrigerant.

Comment: I replaced the fan motor because it was not running and the coils were frozen and the freezer was not cold.  The compressor was running.   Looking back, I think replacing the fan motor was a symptom of a problem with the coils.  Maybe the defrost cycle is not turning on?

Comment: in a small volume of air, left to its own devices, it really should not be freezing up. You might be in a super high humidity environment, but still... if the seal is good it shouldn't flat out turn into a block of ice. I still believe you should check the door seal quality, allllllll the way around.

Answer (score 0):

Fully defrost it (it could be frosted in areas you couldnt see...), and ensure that the door seal is good. If the dollar bill test fails, replace the seal. As for the low freon comment, thats not likely (although possible) because these systems are closed systems.

Comment: Low Freon is the leading cause of icing in my experience, but with other components being changed for ? Reasons and the electrical also ? Based on comment I would not discard the low Freon theory after a manual defrost.